# What does "dataframe[each]" represents in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having an issue understanding a line of code which has been used for one-hot encoding using Pandas in python language

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataframe[each], prefix=each, drop_first=False)
```

I am totally new to this due to which can't figure out the code snippet. I tried looking in the pandas documentation, but didn't find any specific answer. Please if you have the understanding of this line, do let me know. TIA

Here is the One-Hot encoding section.

```
def one_hot(dataframe, col):
for each in col:
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataframe[each], prefix=each, drop_first=False)
    dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, dummies], axis=1)
    dataframe = dataframe.drop(each, 1)
return dataframe
```

Comment: what is `print (each)` ? It seems it is column name (I guess)

Comment: 'print (each)' is outputting 'NameError: each is not defined'. Let me include the one-hot encoding section in the question. I hope you will have a better understanding after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add comments for explain code:

```
def one_hot(dataframe, col):
    #loop by columns names in varible col
    #in another words - for each column processing code bellow
    for each in col:
        #for each column call get_dummies method
        dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataframe[each], prefix=each, drop_first=False)
        #add dummies DataFrame to original DataFrame
        dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, dummies], axis=1)
        #remove column
        dataframe = dataframe.drop(each, 1)
    return dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through each of the columns. "each" indicates one column each time which will perform one-hot encoding.

Also, you are getting a Name Error because your function is not intended correctly

```
def one_hot(dataframe, col):
    for each in col:
        dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataframe[each], prefix=each, drop_first=False)
        dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, dummies], axis=1)
        dataframe = dataframe.drop(each, 1)
    return dataframe
```